# convert tuple of key value pairs to set Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm trying to convert tuple of key value pairs to set to be sent to lambda function environment variables, something like the following:

```
[
    {
      "name"  = "some_name"
      "value" = "some_value"
    },
    {
      "name"  = "some_name"
      "value" = "some_value"
    }
]
```

now, let's say I could save the above into a variable and named it **environmet_variables**

I want to pass it lambda function, so I tried the following:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {

  environment {
    variables = {
        for key, value in var.environment_variables :
        key => value
    }
  }
}
```

it's not working and I get the following error :

```
 var.environment_variables is tuple with 13 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "variables": element "2": string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```tf
{ for variable in var.environment_variables : variable.name => variable.value }
```

It works in a TF console:

```tf
>> env-test.tf
variable "environment_variables" {
  type = list
  default =  [
    {
      "name"  = "key1"
      "value" = "1"
    },
    {
      "name"  = "key2"
      "value" = "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$ terraform console
> { for variable in var.environment_variables : variable.name => variable.value }
{
  "key1" = "1"
  "key2" = "2"
}
```